# vagrant up command issue

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile, vagrant-plugin

I am new with Vagrant. My supervisor want me to run a website. First of all he told me to install VirtualBox and Vagrant. He sent me bootstrap.sh and Vagrantfile files. He told me to copy this in a folder called "data_repo". After that he told me to run "vagrant up" command from "data_repo". I did that but it is giving me following error:

```
A Vagrant environment or target machine is required to run this
command. Run `vagrant init` to create a new Vagrant environment. Or,
get an ID of a target machine from `vagrant global-status` to run
this command on. A final option is to change to a directory with a
Vagrantfile and to try again.
```

Could you please let me know the way to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the contents of bootstrap.sh, and the Vagrantfile.

Comment: you must not be in the `data_repo` directory or the `Vagrantfile` is not present. I think the best way is to go talk to your supervisor and ask him for little support

Comment: Reading the documentation is always helpful. https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a Windows machine and I solved it this way: rename the file Vagrantfile.txt to Vagrantfile (without .txt).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on linux system. By mistake I deleted **Vagrantfile** file.

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one Vagrantfile.
Make sure you have Vagrantfile (V capital and no extension) in that folder(data_repo).

Follow the documentation here

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, only to realize there was a trailing space in the filename `Vagrantfile`. Just had to remove it to get it to work.