# Setting up Vagrant Windows

Tags: command-line, vagrant

I am new to vagrant and I keep getting this error.

[image]

How can I properly run `vagrant up` so that I can continue with the setup process?

Comment: do you have a `Vagrantfile` ? also you confirm you have virtual box (or vmware) installed ?

Comment: I have virtual box. What's a vagrantfile?

Comment: Please paste text of errors in questions, a screenshot is not searchable. The error message is the most important thing here. Searching for that error message leads me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731534/vagrant-up-command-issue

Answer (score 0):

so once you have Vagrant and VirtualBox installed, the next steps are to create a [Vagrantfile](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/) which basically is the configuration file for the VM you will build. It contains [box](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes.html) information as well as [network](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/), [sync folder](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/) and any [provisioning](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/) you'll do on the VM.

for example, if you want to create an ubuntu VM:

```
$ vagrant init <ubuntu/wily64>
$ vagrant up
```

The first command (`vagrant init`) might take some time as it will download a VM from internet but you only run it once. then `vagrant up` will boot the VM